# На 21 строке выводит ошибку: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token. Здесь: line[i] == '%';)

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    string line;
    int count = 0, forcount = 0;
    cout << "Введiть текст коду: ";
    getline(cin, line);

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == 'f' && line[i + 1] == 'o' && line[i + 2] == 'r')
        {
            forcount++;
        }
        if (line[i] == '+')  line[i] == '-';  line[i] == '*';  line[i] == '/';  line[i] == '%';)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Кiлькiсть операторiв: " << count << endl;
    cout << "Кiлькiсть операторiв for: " << forcount << endl;
}
```

Comment: А чего вы хотели добиться этой строчкой: `if (line[i] == '+')  line[i] == '-';  line[i] == '*';  line[i] == '/';  line[i] == '%';)`?

Comment: У Вас две закрывающих скобки стоит... После ```'+'``` и в конце строки.    И вся строка в целом - да, странная какая-то....

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, вместо

```
    if (line[i] == '+')  line[i] == '-';  line[i] == '*';  line[i] == '/';  line[i] == '%';)
    {
        count++;
    }
```

надо написать

```
    if (line[i] == '+' || line[i] == '-' || line[i] == '*' ||  line[i] == '/' ||  line[i] == '%')
    {
        count++;
    }
```

Но будет проще

```
if (strchr("+-*/%",line[i])) count++;
```

Comment: если даже так, то первое условие в вопросе _ UB

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Простите, не понял. О каком условии речь?

Comment: Mikhailo, условие в вопросе _ line[i] == 'f' && line[i + 1] == 'o' && line[i + 2] == 'r'